# Prestashop: Manually aproove order before bank-wire payment for selected group

Tags: php, prestashop, payment, prestashop-1.6

In Prestashop 1.6

I got one customer group (wholesallers) that needs its orders to be confirmed before they are able to pay with bank-wire.

How to do that? I wonder if it's possible to create special order status for this group, which is set just after placing order and then manually change to status "waiting for bank-wire". But I can't see such option.

Thanks in advance for any help, clues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible via GUI, you will have to code it.

Maybe the easiest option will be to copy the Wire Payment module and then enable one module for one group and the another module for the wholesellers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to Customers > Groups. Edit each group and disable the bank wire option for the group you do not want to have a bank wire option.